# html_quick_form vs manual validation

Tags: php, asp.net, quickform

I have been working with the asp.net for sometime but now thinking to learn php. I am tired of the way asp.net is imposing limitation by taking away the freedom to render the html on page and imposing ViewState. I am studying php and feels simple but now I saw Html_Quick_Form Validation Library. and I felt like this is imposing the same limitation by giving a few functions and halts the ability to write fully customized code. Am I right here?

Comment: No, it allows you to inject your own code if you want to. But my professional recommendation is to *stay the hell away* from that library because it's crap.

Comment: Thanks @John I am like snake bitten by asp.net and I don't want someone else to generate stupid code for me. Glade that I asked!